# How to use "sous vide" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, idioms

First, I'm not sure if *sous vide* is a trademark or just a cooking method like boil or fry.

How should I use *sous vide* in a sentence when writing a recipe?

Comment: Sous vide: ( French for "under vacuum") is a method of cooking food sealed in airtight plastic bags in a water bath or in a temperature-controlled steam environment .http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-vide

Comment: The sous-vide method is used in many high end gourmet restaurants by chefs.Sous-vide has become a common feature on television cooking shows. Non-professional cooks are also beginning to use sous-vide cooking: https://www.polyscienceculinary.com/blog/sous-vide-recipes/

Comment: sous-vide is a stupid wank that some pretentious fools who have seen TV shows about "molekulurr cookin'", or too much Heston Blumenthal, turn in to cheesey business plans.  :)

Comment: Sous vide sure sounds a lot fancier than "boil in a bag" which is how I learned it.

Comment: Have you visited the SE Q&A site for cookery enthusiasts yet?

Comment: @Kris I could'n find it. Have a link? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a trade mark:

> - *Set the temperature of the Sous-vide Pro to 65C*
> - Place the sealed bag in the water....

It can be just a pan of water

> - Prepare a sous-vide by heating a pan of water to 65C
> - Place the sealed bag in the water....